# How can I store the selected semantic UI dropdown option in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

I have a dropdown list with 5 options. I need to save the selected option to my state as `listValue`.

#### My list of options and the state

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: 'OK', value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: 'Avvikelse', value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: 'Ej Relevant', value: 3 },
  { key: 4, text: 'Observation', value: 4 },
  { key: 5, text: 'Saknas', value: 5 },
]
export default class ConfirmationModal extends React.Component {
  state = {
  listValue: 'Status'
}
```

#### My list (from semantic-ui)

```
dropDownList = () => (
  <Dropdown
    placeholder={this.state.listValue}
    clearable
    options={options}
    selection
  />
)
```

How can I store the selected option in my state?

Comment: ``how i can store the users option into the state`` do you want to pass the same exact values from options to listValue? Duplicating an array?

Comment: Not quite,
the desire is to setState of the option into 'listValue'. Change the current state value.

Comment: Use [setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Comment: You just want to store a single option in listValue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onChange` handler and put the `value` given to the handler in your component state.

**Example**

```
const options = [
  { key: 1, text: "OK", value: 1 },
  { key: 2, text: "Avvikelse", value: 2 },
  { key: 3, text: "Ej Relevant", value: 3 },
  { key: 4, text: "Observation", value: 4 },
  { key: 5, text: "Saknas", value: 5 }
];

class DropdownExampleControlled extends React.Component {
  state = {
    options,
    value: options[0].value
  };

  handleChange = (_e, { value }) => this.setState({ value });

  render() {
    const { value, options } = this.state;
    const currentOption = options.find(o => o.value === value);

    return (
      <Grid columns={2}>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Dropdown
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            options={options}
            placeholder="Choose an option"
            selection
            value={value}
          />
        </Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column>
          <Segment secondary>
            <pre>Current value: {currentOption.text}</pre>
          </Segment>
        </Grid.Column>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to update additional keys to state in `handleChange`. In my most recent post I'm struggling to update a `key` other than `value` to state when a selection is made

Answer (score 1):

As I understood you, you need to save in the state the values, which user selected?
If yes, You need have an event for example onChange, which means that user seelct that particular option from list. and set it in state

```
onChange(selectedValue) {

  this.setState({listValue: selectedValue});

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this function to your component:

```
handleChange = (_p, { value }) => {
  this.setState({ listValue: value});
};
```

add it as prop to your Dropdown:

```
<Dropdown onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder={this.state.listValue} clearable options={options} selection />
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle state management using `setState`. Simple example:

**Example** [Sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6qkph3)

```
const options = [
      { key: 1, text: 'OK', value: 1 },
      { key: 2, text: 'Avvikelse', value: 2 },
      { key: 3, text: 'Ej Relevant', value: 3 },
      { key: 4, text: 'Observation', value: 4 },
      { key: 5, text: 'Saknas', value: 5 },
    ]

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      listValue: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() //before render
  {
    this.setState({
      listValue: options[1].text  //storing text from second line
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.listValue}
      </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

This displays: Avvikelse